# What verb tense should I use after “did”

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I know you are suppose to use the present verb tense after DID, “ I did do my homework”  “ I didn’t go to the park”. But what about: “I DID what you TOLD me?”, I know this is correct, but why? Isn’t it suppose to be: “ I did what you tell me”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how you use the verb **did**.

If you use it as an auxiliary verb (**did say, did do, did think) the main verb has to be in the base form.

However this is not the case when you use **did** as the main verb.

In your sentence, **did** is not an auxiliary verb.

What you are saying really is **I did it**. But instead of **it**, the object of **did** is the noun clause **what you told me**.

If, for example, you wanted to emphasise that you did it, you would write:

> I did do/say what you told me.

Here **did** acts as the auxiliary verb and **do** or **say** is in the base form.

https://www.k12reader.com/term/noun-clause/
[What verb to use after "did"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127057/what-verb-to-use-after-did)

Answer (score -1):

I did do my homework ---> "**did** (*an auxiliary verb*)" and "**do** (*the main verb*)"

I DID what you TOLD me ---> "**DID** (*the main verb of the main clause*, i.e. I DID)", "**what you TOLD me** (*a noun clause*)" and "**TOLD** (*the main verb of the noun clause*)"
there should be a proportion between the tense of the main clause and the noun clause.

> I went before you came.