# Who did you say that to?

Tags: prepositions, questions, present-tense

Are both correct? Do they mean the same?

> Who did you tell (about) that?
> Who did you say that to?

Comment: "Who did you said that to?" is incorrect.  If you are using a "helping" verb, like *do*, you conjugate that one and not the main verb, like "did you say", not "did you *said*"; "does he eat", not "does he *eats*", etc.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, of course, I know about questions in the past simple, I simply mistyped, I've corrected it now. The question is not that. The question is about "Who did you say that to?" and "Who did you tell that?"

Comment: You mis-typed it twice but only fixed one. I don't see this as anything more than a proofreading question. There's no real explanation of what exactly you're looking for except confirmation or correction.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. They can't see the forest for the trees. Focus on the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definitely  needs either the "about" or a trailing "to" and in the second it should be "say" not "said".

That is: "Who did you tell about that" or "Who did you tell that to?"
and
"Who did you say that to?"

Their meanings are pretty much the same, although the first pair is slightly less formal.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence: **Who did you tell about that?** sounds strange but is possible.

It would sound completely natural if you simply added an object. **Who did you tell about that accident?**

If you omit **about**, the question needs to change to either:
**Who did you tell that to?** or, the more formal, **To whom did you tell that?**

If you simply asked: **Who did you tell about?**, it sounds as though you mean **Who did you talk about?**, possibly in a context of telling tales about others' misdeeds.

Your second example is simply wrong. While the auxiliary verb **did** is in the past tense, it requires the main verb that follows to be in its base form. **Who did you say that to?**

You will find numerous sites that illustrate this rule, including the one below.

[What verb to use after "did"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127057/what-verb-to-use-after-did)

Comment: Yes, of course, I know about questions in the past simple, I simply mistyped, I've corrected it now.  The question is about "Who did you say that to?" and "Who did you tell that?"